# Receiver, that was created from IntentService, doesn't work

Tags: android, android-intentservice, android-broadcastreceiver

I have Geofence IntentService. On GEOFENCE_ENTER I create broadcast receiver. But it doesn't get actions.

If I created it in MainActivity - all is good. But I don't need to.

I do not understand what happens when I create the receiver from the service.

```
    public class GeofenceTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {

    ...

        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
           ...

           if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER) {

                //Create WiFi scan receiver
                WiFiScanReceiver wifiScan = new WiFiScanReceiver();
                registerReceiver(wifiScan, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));

                //Scan
                WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                Boolean scanStarted = wm.startScan();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `registerReceiver()` in `onHandleIntent()` will not work well. Your receiver will go away microseconds later, after `onHandleIntent()` returns and the service stops itself.

Either use a manifest-registered receiver, or use a regular `Service` instead of an `IntentService`, managing your own background thread and arranging to `stopSelf()` the service when you are done with it.

Answer (score 0):

`IntentService` will be destroyed once `onHandleIntent()` finished.
You should use `Service`